# How do i print statements using debug in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

The file `main.yaml` inside a role is below where I want to print some message like "Directory created/existed". When I use something like below I get the error -

> ERROR: multiple actions specified in task: 'file' and 'Ensuring that directory exists to download the artifacts'

`---
 - name: Ensuring that directory exists to download the artifacts
   debug:
     msg: "Directory Created/Existed"
   file:
     path: "{{ local_server_release_location }}"
     state: directory`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use both `debug` and `file` modules in one task.

Instead, given the directory shall be present at localhost, create the directory and test its existence. For example

```
 - name: Create directory
   file:
     path: "{{ local_server_release_location }}"
     state: directory
   delegate_to: localhost

 - name: Ensuring that directory exists to download the artifacts
   debug:
     msg: "Directory exists"
   when: local_server_release_location is directory
```

Comment: It doesn't work with any module i guess. I tried to use as below but still got the same error - 

**` - name: Copy the release from local server to all tomcat nodes
   debug:
     msg: "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
   copy: src={{local_server_release_location}}/{{item}}-{{release_version}}.war dest={{tomcat_server_release_location}}/Release{{release_version}}/{{item}}
   with_items:
    - "{{ webapps }}"`**

Comment: Right. Only one module per task.